# Convert multiples sequences from fastq to fasta in a folder

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, fasta, fastq

I want to convert all the fastq files contained in a folder to fasta format, each file will keep the original name but in fasta extension, I have made the next code in perl, however it only extract the last sequence of each file !!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($dir, $files, $file_name, $file_format);

    GetOptions (
                'dr=s'  =>\$dir
                );

foreach $files (glob("$dir/*.fastq")) {
        open LINE, "<", $files or die "can't read open $files";
            while(
                    defined(my $head    = <LINE>)       &&
                    defined(my $seq     = <LINE>)       &&
                    defined(my $qhead   = <LINE>)       &&
                    defined(my $quality = <LINE>)           
            ){
                        substr($head, 0, 1, '>'); 
                        ($file_name, $file_format) = split (/\./,$files);
                        open OUTFILE, '>', $file_name.".fasta";
                        print OUTFILE $head, $seq;
            }
}
close LINE;
close OUTFILE;
exit;
```

and extra question, I want to use the pice next code, as a subroutine, I want to develop the same scrip to have the option of convert all fastq files in a folder or single file to fasta file !!!

```
while(
                        defined(my $head    = <LINE>)       &&
                        defined(my $seq     = <LINE>)       &&
                        defined(my $qhead   = <LINE>)       &&
                        defined(my $quality = <LINE>)           
                ){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda of new to perl myself and don't know a thing about bioinformatics, but it looks like you are overwriting the output file with every turn of the while loop.   I think you want to append to the file so you want a >> not just >.  example

```
open OUTFILE, '>>', $file_name.".fasta";
```

Hope that helps.